# How to fix select filter on category

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, filters

I created a filter where I can filter on different types of machines by a custom taxonomy. It shows the right taxonomies in the filter and after submitting the right url is shown. Problem is that despite of these good things the archive still shows all the machines, and not only the one with the matching taxonomy.

Anyone who can help me?

The code I used is

```
function MachineSoortMagni() { 
//Labels voor de custom taxonomy
     $labels = array(
       'name' => _x( 'Types', 'type-magni' ),
       'singular_name' => _x( 'Type', 'type' ),
       'search_items' =>  __( 'Zoek Types' ),
       'all_items' => __( 'Alle Types' ),
       'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Type' ),
       'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Type:' ),
       'edit_item' => __( 'Bewerk Type' ), 
       'update_item' => __( 'Update Type' ),
       'add_new_item' => __( 'Voeg nieuw Type toe' ),
       'new_item_name' => __( 'Nieuwe Type naam' ),
       'menu_name' => __( 'Types' ),
     );    
    
   // Taxonomy registreren
     register_taxonomy('type-magni',array('magni'), array(
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'labels' => $labels,
       'show_ui' => true,
       'show_in_rest' => true,
       'show_admin_column' => true,
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'type-magni' ),
     ));
    
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'MachineSoortMagni', 0 );

function filterTypeMagni(){
    echo 'Soort machine: ';
    echo '<form method="GET" class="custom-filter">';
    echo '<select name="orderby" id="orderby"><option value="">Soort machine</option>';
            $terms = get_terms([
                'taxonomy' => 'type-magni',
                'hide_empty' => 'false'
            ]);
            foreach ($terms as $term) :
                echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '" name="type-magni[]">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                                
            
            endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        echo '<button type="submit">Filter</button>';
    echo '</form>';
}
add_shortcode('filter_type_magni', 'filterTypeMagni');
```

Comment: where is your shortcode being used? I do not see any code to display the machines in your question, is there code missing? Would it not make more sense to use the archive URLs/templates that already exist instead of building a page template then reinventing all of that via shortcodes? Your taxonomy already has archives that filter out of the box e.g. example.com/type-magni/foo

Comment: @TomJNowell I used the shortcode in a ACF field that I implented in the archive template. By using this field I give my clients a little bit more freedom by entering extra content around the shortcode so no, there is no code missing. And I don't know what you mean with the build-in url-templates for custom taxonomies. Do you know if there is any documentation about that?

Comment: The weird thing is that it does work with checkboxxes, but it just won't with select

Comment: can you be specific about what you mean by archive template? Because archive template has a very specific meaning and it's unlikely you meant that meaning based on your response. E.g. is this a page template that implements an archive? What is the filename? How are you inserting the shortcode? The exact specific terminology matters, e.g. I suspect you're trying to use URL query variables to change the results of the post archive for your custom taxonomy, but you've just said you had no idea that post archive existed which implies a page template. **How are you displaying machines?**